# What is the right Entity-Type for Azure Table Storage with Azure App Services

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-table-storage

I'm testing the Todo-Item-Example from the Azure-WebSite with Azure App Services and Azure Table Storage.

In the Azure-Download-Example the `DataEntity-Class` inherit from `EntityData`, but in all other tutorials the `DataEntity-Class` inherit from 
`TableEntity` and in a *Update-Paper* from **Sep 2015** the `DataEntity-Class` inherit from `StorageData`.

Please tell me, what is the right and the newest way.

**Backround:**

I want to set the `partitionKey` and the `rowKey` in the Azure Table Storage.

How could I set the `partitionKey` and the `rowKey` with `StorageData` or `EntityData`. Only in the `TableEntity` I can set these keys, but then I have also to implement the `ITableData-Interface` to use the `TodoItem` in my `TableController`.

Comment: Hi, can you provide links to the samples that you are looking at that inherit from EntityData or StorageData? I will take a look at these to make sure they are not providing out of date information. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, the Sample is the current BackEnd-Download-Sample from portal.azure.com after creating the Mobile App Service (c#-Backend).

  public class TodoItem : EntityData
    {
 public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
 public bool Complete { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to inherit from `TableEntity`. Please take a look at our Table storage sample code here for an example of a class that inherits from `TableEntity`:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-table-dotnet-getting-started/blob/master/TableStorage/Model/CustomerEntity.cs

Comment: But EntityData is the base class provided in the QuickStart code--there must be a reason for that. The comments say that EntityData is the common implementation to work with EntityFramework. If we switch the code as you suggest, will that not break EntityFramework?

Answer (score 0):

I switched it to use `StorageData` instead of `EntityData`. It implements the same interface, and provides accessors for `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`. It can be found in the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Storage package.